# Adding arrays of variable length

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix

One of my functions generates a result as a variable-length list, like [1, 2, 3, ...] etc. As these lists come out, I would like to add them all to some master list in this fashion:

```
out: [1, 2]
out: [3] 
  sum:[4,2]
out: [0, 0, 0, 2] 
  sum: [4, 2, 0, 2]
out: [3, 1] 
  sum: [7, 3, 0, 2]
```

and so on.

I also need to be able to do operations on these - something like:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4]/N = [1/N, 2/N, ...]
```

Are numpy arrays the format I want? I can't seem to get it to work.

Comment: The latter is definitely possible and easily and efficiently done with NumPy.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the functionality done with map/itertools.izip_longest in python 2.x or itertools.zip_longest in python 3.x

With that said,

- iterate through all elements in the result of map function
- for `each` sublist, you can use the sum() inbuilt function of python.
- to handle the none values, check if `None` is present in `each` variable. If present, then iterate through that sublist, every element `i` is checked if that is None, if so, then replace it with 0.

That is,

```
>>> addFn = lambda a,b: [sum(each) if None not in each else sum(i if i else 0 for i in each )for each in map(None,a,b)]
>>> addFn([1,2,3],[4])
[5, 2, 3]
>>> addFn(addFn([1,2,3],[4]),[7,3,0,2])
[12, 5, 3, 2]
```

And for the second functionality, if `l` if your list, then

For every element `i` in l, convert either numerator or denominator float and perform the operation!

```
>>> divByN = lambda l,N:[i/float(N) for i in l]
>>> divByN([5,6,7,8],2)
[2.5, 3.0, 3.5, 4.0]
```

As mentioned by Baldrickk, here is an example with itertools,

```
from itertools import izip_longest as izip_l 
sum = [a+b for a,b in izip_l(arr1,arr2, fillvalue=0)]
```

Comment: I was going to provide an izip_longest answer, but I see you mentioned it. you didn't provide an example though, so feel free to use: `from itertools import izip_longest as izip_l`
`sum = [a+b for a,b in izip_l(arr1,arr2, fillvalue=0)]
`

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np

def Add(a, b):
    a, b = map(np.array, (a, b))
    if a.size > b.size: 
        a[:b.size] += b
        return a
    else:
        b[:a.size] += a
        return b
```

Example usage:

```
>>> Add([1,2], [3])
array([ 4.,  2.])
>>> Add([0,0,0,2], _)
array([ 4.,  2.,  0.,  2.])
```

The first line of the function is there to get a copy of these arrays converted to floating point, so you could divide without rounding later.

Comment: `a, b = map(np.asfarray, (a, b))` super hard to read. Why not simply `a = a.astype(float)` and `b = b.astype(float)`? Also, why should `Add` care about the division later? The developer should themselves cast to `float` if they decide they need a division.

Comment: @NilsWerner, because this looks simpler and cleaner to me (and super easy to read) and also requires one line less and produces the same result.

Comment: The fact that you needed to explain the line in your text says that it is in fact harder to read to anyone else but you.

Comment: @NilsWerner, it's there to explain that one must copy the arrays first in order to use that method. It's up to the OP to decide _how_ to copy them.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution:

```
def add_shortest(a, b):
    a = numpy.array(a)
    b = numpy.array(b)

    common_length = min(a.size, b.size)
    a[:common_length] += b[:common_length]
    return a

add_shortest(numpy.arange(2), numpy.arange(3))  # array([0, 2])
add_shortest(numpy.arange(3), numpy.arange(3))  # array([0, 2, 4])
add_shortest(numpy.arange(3), numpy.arange(2))  # array([0, 2, 2])
add_shortest(add_shortest([0, 0, 0, 2], add_shortest([1, 2], [3])), [3, 1])  # array([7, 3, 0, 2])
```

Comment: I think this only works if your shortest matrix is the first argument - in this case we don't know the lengths.

Comment: I checked, it works in both cases. The way you phrased your question it sounds like you always want to return an array the same length as argument `a`.